# jquery (this) cross function

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery get .val](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490563/jquery-get-val)

I have revised this question. What I need is the "this" value of

```
( $(this).attr("value"));
```

to show up in the "this" of

```
$("#activities_" +btn_id).val($(this).val());
```

Here is the code.

```
$('.thoughts_list').click(function(){
    ( $(this).attr('id'));
    ( $(this).attr("value"));
}); 
    $('#close_thoughts').click(function(){

    $("#activities_" +btn_id).val($(this).val());   
});
```

Currently, the value that is returned is "Cancel", which is the value of the "#close_thoughts", instead I need the value of the clicked ".thoughts list"

Comment: `( $(this).attr('id'));` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why are you binding a click handler inside a click handler?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: The first click is getting the value of a radio input, the second click is supposed to place that value into the "#activities_" +btn_id".val, but only after the second click.

Comment: Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Do you mean `var btn_id=$(this).attr('id');`

Comment: I shall try, it may take me a bit, never used it before.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LsqCW/

Comment: Quite a horrible list of thoughts you got going in that fiddle.

Comment: lol, it is, supposed to be for a moms stop smoking website ~,~

Comment: So, I think we just need to know what you are trying to do here.  With the dialog box, it seems that you want to add individual items to a list when selected, and then have one more button show the selected items in a 'popup'.  is that accurate?

Comment: All of the comments above this one are no longer valid to the revised question.

Answer (score 2):

```
var btn_id = '';
var radio_value = '';

$('.thoughts_list').click(function(){
    btn_id = this.id;
    radio_value = $('someRadioElement').prop('value');
});

$('.close_thoughts').click(function(){
    $( "#activities_" + btn_id ).val( radio_value  );
});
```

Comment: That didn't quite work, I guess i'm having trouble saying what I need. Ill come back later to try and clear up my question.

Comment: @user1978497 you're welcome to do so, I'll take a look later to your question