# Jquery get .val

Tags: jquery

What I need is the "this" value of

```
( $(this).attr("value"));
```

to show up in the "this" of

```
$("#activities_" +btn_id).val($(this).val());
```

Here is the code.

```
$('.thoughts_list').click(function(){
    ( $(this).attr('id'));
    ( $(this).attr("value"));
}); 
    $('#close_thoughts').click(function(){

    $("#activities_" +btn_id).val($(this).val());   
});
```

Currently, the value that is returned is "Cancel", which is the value of the "#close_thoughts", instead I need the value of the clicked ".thoughts list"

ANSWERED, apperantly this is what i was looking for.

```
$('.thoughts_list').click(function(){
    ( $(this).attr('id'));
    ( $(this).attr("value"));
}); 
    $('#close_thoughts').click(function(){

    $("#activities_" +btn_id).val($('input[name=thoughts_list]:checked').val());    
});
```

Comment: But `$("#activities_" +btn_id).val($(this).val());` is inside `$('#close_thoughts').click(function(){` handler... how do you know which `.thoughts_list` is clicked?

Comment: This may not fix your problem, but it's a good idea none the less. replace $(this).attr("id") with `this.id`, and `$(this).attr("value")` with `$(this).val()` if it's a `select/radio/checkbox`, or `this.value` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the `.thoughts_list` element when you click the `#close_thoughts` element you'll need this:

```
$('#close_thoughts').click(function(){
    $("#activities_" + btn_id).val($('.thoughts_list').val());   
});
```

Your code was setup as follows:

```
$('#close_thoughts').click(function(){
    $("#activities_" +btn_id).val($(this).val());   
});
```

The problem here is that on the 2nd line `$(this).val()` is the same as `$('#close_thoughts').val()` and you're looking for `$('.thoughts_list').val()`.

Comment: There are a number of values that .thoughts_list can return. I need it to be the exact value that is clicked from .thoughts_list.

Comment: Whatever you select on the `.thoughts_list` -- it's value can be retrieved with `$('.thoughts_list').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps?

```
$('.thoughts_list').on('click', function() {
    $("#activities_" + this.id).val(this.value);
});
```

Your question is quite cryptic. Are you trying to change the value for the element with an ID of `activities_` + the ID of the clicking element? If so, the above will work. If not, you need to elucidate your situation a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

This is what my boss gave me to work with.

```
$('.thoughts_list').click(function(){
    ( $(this).attr('id'));
    ( $(this).attr("value"));
}); 
    $('#close_thoughts').click(function(){

    $("#activities_" +btn_id).val($('input[name=thoughts_list]:checked').val());    
});
```

Comment: 'input[name=thoughts_list]:checked' is what I specifically was looking for